# What happens when an integer element in a list is changed to string in java?

Tags: java

I have an array list. In that list I have a couple of string elements and few integer elements. I need to change all the elements in my arraylist to string so that I can modify the string elements. So, when I am doing this, even the integer elements in my arraylist are being changed to string. Would that be a problem if tried to access the integer elements after they are changed to string?

Comment: Please show code to clarify exactly what you have and what you're trying to do. I suspect an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: How is your list declared, created, and populated? Typically it is not a good idea to mix non-related types like this.

Comment: List foo = new ArrayList()
If there are integers elements in the list, I want them to remain the same. I am guessing if I changes the integer elements and I try to access it would I still get the same value? Hope I am making sense.

Comment: Please show more code, *real* code as an edit to your question. The details are very important. I agree with @Code-Guru that it sounds like you're adding Integers and Strings to a List which is something that you should not be doing, and we need to see why you think you need to do this. It is highly likely that there's a much better way to solve the overall problem that you're trying to solve, but we need to first understand your code and your overall problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use parseInt() so no it is not a problem. You can read more here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't attempt to alter the types of elements contained in a list. Instead, create a *new* list of strings, and add to it appropriately:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(integers.size());

for (Integer a : integers)
    strings.add(a.toString());
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did not declare string when i created my list. I did this List foo = new ArrayList()

Comment: @rajubhai Then you are using a raw type, which is bad. You should parametrize `List` and `ArrayList` as done in my code snippet.